# Tic Tac Toe / Noughts and Crosses - Game End Result Printing Twice

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is the first program I have tried to make. Its a simple game of noughts and crosses. Its written in Python 3.6.

I have tested it and when the game finishes, the tie/win message is printed twice but I cannot see why.

Any help regarding this or any other improvements are appreciated. Many Thanks.

I have included only the player 1 code so I can post the question.

```
#Grid
grid = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
print("Welcome to Noughts and Crosses Game")
p1_name = input("What is name of Player 1? Player 1 is 'x': ")

#Draw Grid
def draw_grid():
    print("-------------")
    print('|', grid[0], '|', grid[1], '|', grid[2], '|')
    print("-------------")
    print('|', grid[3], '|', grid[4], '|', grid[5], '|')
    print("-------------")
    print('|', grid[6], '|', grid[7], '|', grid[8], '|')
    print("-------------")

#Move input for player 1 
def p1():
        try:
            p1_input = int(input(p1_name + " select a space on the grid by entering a \
number to place an 'x': "))
        except ValueError:
            print("Error: Please enter a number, not a letter or symbol")
            p1()
        else:
            if p1_input not in range(9):
                print("Error: Please select a number on the grid 0-8 to place an 'x'")
                p1()
            elif grid[p1_input] == "x" or grid[p1_input] == "o":
                print("Error: This spot has been taken.")
                p1()
            else:
                grid[p1_input] = "x"
                draw_grid()

#Check for three x in a row
def p1_check():
    if grid[0] == "x" and grid[1] == "x" and grid[2] == "x" or \
        grid[3] == "x" and grid[4] == "x" and grid[5] == "x" or \
        grid[6] == "x" and grid[7] == "x" and grid[8] == "x" or \
        grid[0] == "x" and grid[3] == "x" and grid[6] == "x" or \
        grid[1] == "x" and grid[4] == "x" and grid[7] == "x" or \
        grid[2] == "x" and grid[5] == "x" and grid[8] == "x" or \
        grid[6] == "x" and grid[4] == "x" and grid[2] == "x" or \
        grid[0] == "x" and grid[4] == "x" and grid[8] == "x":
            print(p1_name + " Wins!")
            return "End Game"      

#Check for a tie
def tie_check():
    if grid.count("x") + grid.count("o") == len(grid):
        print("Game is a tie")
        return "End Game"

def play():
    draw_grid()
    while True:
        p1()
        p1_check()
        if p1_check() == "End Game":
            break
        tie_check()
        if tie_check() == "End Game":
            break

play()
```

Comment: Random aside: here is a nice way to draw the grid: https://repl.it/repls/PinkBogusStacks

Answer (score 1):

```
    p1_check()
    if p1_check() == "End Game":
        break
    tie_check()
    if tie_check() == "End Game":
        break
```

You are running p1_check() and tie_check() twice. Store the output of p1_check() and tie_check() in variables to avoid the double print.

```
    ended = p1_check()
    if ended == "End Game":
        break
    tied = tie_check()
    if tied == "End Game":
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Because p1_check and tie_check are executed twice.
Once just before the if-statement and then again in the if-statement

I reccommend removing the calls just before the if-statement